# `pgeom` in `R` does not seem to exhibit memorylessness as expected

Tags: r, exponential-distribution, geometric-distribution

The geometric and exponential distributions exhibit memorylessness, i.e.,
$$ P(X \geq k + j)=P(X\geq k)P(X\geq j) $$

This can be shown for an arbitrary exponential distribution using `R`:

```
> pexp(q=1, rate=1, lower.tail = F)
[1] 0.3678794
> pexp(q=0.2, rate=1, lower.tail = F)*pexp(q=0.8, rate=1, lower.tail = F)
[1] 0.3678794
```

This same result should hold for the geometric distribution. However, when I perform a similar calculation using `pgeom()`, I do not get the same result

```
> pgeom(q=3, prob=0.2, lower.tail = F)
[1] 0.4096
> pgeom(q=1, prob=0.2, lower.tail = F)*pgeom(q=2, prob=0.2, lower.tail = F)
[1] 0.32768
```

Can someone help explain this discrepancy? Based on these examples, the geometric distribution as calculated by `pgeom` does not exhibit memorylessness.

Comment: Welcome to CV. The memorylessness is for a r.v.  $X$ taking values
$1$, $2$, $\dots$ and representing the number of *trials* needed to
reach the $1$-st success, while the geometric distribution in R is for
the number $Y$ of *failures* before the first success, with values
$0$, $1$, $\dots$. In distribution $X = Y +1$. In R `pgeom(k, prob = p, lower.tail = FALSE)` gives $P(Y > k) = (1 - p)^{k+1}$ for $k=0$, $1$, $\dots$.

Comment: If you adjust for the support, you will find for example `pgeom(q=9-1,prob=0.2,lower.tail=F)` and `pgeom(q=3-1,prob=0.2,lower.tail=F) * pgeom(q=6-1,prob=0.2,lower.tail=F)` give the same `0.2097152` and similarly for other examples

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thank you for the follow-up, Henry. My misunderstanding was a difference in convention. A similar explanation in https://doi.org/10.1002/9781119536963.ch10 in case helpful for others: "$X$ calculations in R correspond to our $X+1$ calculations above. For example, $X=0$ in R means zero failures before first success, which is equivalent to $X=1$, the first success occurs in the first trial, in our model." Also, in case others use the above commands, the probability is `0.1342177`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The memorylessness is for a r.v.  $X$ taking values
$1$, $2$, $\dots$ and representing the number of *trials* needed to
reach the $1$-st success in a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials, while the geometric distribution in R is for the number $Y$ of *failures* before the first success, with values $0$, $1$, $\dots$. In distribution $X = Y +1$. In R `pgeom(k, prob = p, lower.tail = FALSE)` gives $P(Y > k) = (1 - p)^{k+1}$ for $k \geqslant 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wanted to clarify that `dgeom` in R does not have an argument `lower.tail`. Also, is there a way to express the property of memorylessness of the geometric distribution in R as I did with the `pexp` function?

Comment: @Henry Thanks for fixing the typo.